# Angular 2 EventEmitter apparently not emitting in test

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, testing, eventemitter

This is starting to feel bewitched. After having read the [Angular guide](https://angular.io/guide/testing#test-a-component-with-inputs-and-outputs) multiple times today, I cannot get my test to pass, and cannot figure out why.

[stackblitz example](https://angular-dn71sa.stackblitz.io) (of course here the spy expectation works, but not the other one)

**component.html**

```
<button (click)="download()" title="Save report to your computer">
  Download
</button>
```

**component.ts**

```
export class ExtractModalComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() downloadRequest: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

  constructor(public activeModal: NgbActiveModal) {}

  download() {
    this.downloadRequest.emit({ fromDate: this.fromDateTime, toDate: this.toDateTime });
  }
}
```

**component.spec.ts**

```
it('should raise the downloadRequest event when the download button is clicked, and send the dates', () => {
  let dates = {};
  let spy = spyOn(comp.downloadRequest, 'emit');
  let dt = moment(new Date(2018, 0, 1, 13, 0, 0)).format();
  comp.downloadRequest.subscribe(result => {
    dates = result;
  });
  click(page.downloadBtn); //click helper borrowed from Angular guide; calls either el.click() or el.triggerEvent('click', eventObj)
  //have also tried just comp.download(), but that doesn't make a difference
  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled(); //fails: "Expected spy emit to have been called"
  expect(dates).toEqual({ fromDate: dt, toDate: dt }); //fails: Expected Object({  }) to equal Object({ fromDate: '2018-01-01T13:00:00-05:00', toDate: '2018-01-01T13:00:00-05:00' })
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. To me it looks almost exactly like the example in the guides, but for some reason, their test passes and mine doesn't.

Comment: What is the parent component that listens for this event? I think you are testing on the wrong component?

Comment: There is a parent component, but this component is a ng-bootstrap modal entry component, so the parent doesn't use the component's selector; it just opens the modal in code, and subscribes to the event: `this.extractModalRef.componentInstance.downloadRequest.subscribe($e => { console.log($e.fromDate, $e.toDate); });` In any case, the angular guide itself shows testing a child component like this.

Answer (score 0):

Well I feel sheepish...

As per the Angular guides, I was using a Page class to avoid having to query elements in my tests, and in setting up the page, I created a spy on the download function, and completely spaced that it will always be used, so while `download()` was being called, nothing inside it was!

In any case, in an effort to solve this problem, I ended up moving code from the parent component to the child, since it really belonged there anyway, and eliminated the cross-talk and having to subscribe to the event. But that answers why it worked live and not in the test! I knew it had to be something about the test environment!